# Динамическое выделение памяти для массива структур

Tags: c, структуры, память, c++

Как правильно выделять и освобождать память для массива структур, которая в свою очередь содержит двумерный(матрицу) массив? :

```
#define  N           5000    
#define  DAYS        700
#define  ChCount     500 
struct Ch
{
   int **Days;
   int Length;
} RCh;  

int main (void)
{
   Ch *RCh = new Ch[ChCount]; 
   for (int i = 0; i<ChCount; i++)
   {
      RCh[i].Days = new int* [N];
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      RCh[i].Days[j] = new int[DAYS];
   }

//операции с массивом RCh[N].Days[N][DAYS]
   delete[] RCh;
}
```

*В итоге имеет место ошибка:*

Необработанное исключение в "0x757ec6e3" в "data.exe": Исключение Microsoft C++:

> std::bad_alloc по адресу 0x00113744..

Но если использовать такую запись:

```
struct Ch
{
   int Days[N][DAYS]
   int Length;
} RCh; 

int main(void)
{
    Ch *RCh;  
    RCh = (Ch*)malloc(ChCount*sizeof(Ch));
}
```

то проблем не возникает, однако только при маленьких числах N(<1500).

Answer (score 6):

Что бы выделить количество памяти которое вы хотите выделить вам надо очень много оперативы на компьютере ))

Посчитайте сколько памяти надо при ваших числах.

5000 * 700 * 500 * sizeof(int) = количество байт. 
количество байт / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = количество гигобайт оперативки 
У меня получилось 6.5 Гигов ))

Вот и выскакивает исключение которое говорит что не может выделить память.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! ))

Answer (score 2):

Вы действительно хотите слишком много пвмяти выделить. Система не может вам предоставить место для 1 750 000 000 чисел типа int. Лично мне удалось выпросить только 2 989 999.